# Mixed execution of two Python scripts & DatastaxBulk loader scripts to load to .csv in Apache Cassandra

Tags: python, csv, ubuntu, cassandra, datastax

I have a .sh file in which I call two python scripts:

for fileMaster.sh :

```
python script1.py && python script2.py
```

now, the problem is that I want to add the action that after the script2.py do the upload into Apache Cassandra with Datastax bulk loader.

so, if I do this;

```
python script1.py && python script2.py && fileSlave.sh
```

in with fileSlave.sh is:

```
export PATH=/home/mypc/dsbulk-1.7.0/bin:$PATH

source ~/.bashrc

dsbulk load -url /home/mypc/Desktop/foldertest/data.csv -k data_test -t data_table  -delim "," -header true -m '0=time_exp, 1=p'
```

it gives to me access denied to load into Cassandra. As imagine, the impossibility to do the same if I add the code of fileSlave.sh directly under the py calls in fileMaster.sh

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem cause the file fileMaster.sh need this:

```
python script1.py && python script2.py

chmod u+x ./shell2.sh
./fileSlave.sh
```

It works!